# How do I add these dependencies?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am very new to React Native.
I am trying to install react-native-router-flux on my project following this website

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

One of the steps refers to users with React Native 0.60 and higher.
For android users it says to "add the following two lines to dependencies section in android/app/build.gradle:"

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Although I don't know how to do this
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]So you need to open the file you mentioned and search for the word **dependencies** followed by curly brackets. Inside the brackets (and exactly where the red arrow is pointing) you need to paste the code they’re telling you to add:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

You should find at least two entries that start with the word implementation and that are already inside the dependencies list (before the red arrow).
To find it faster, in you editor you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if you use MacOS.

Comment: }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01 androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02"

Comment: Is it like this sir?

Comment: And by the way, is it always this way when I have to add a dependecy manually?

Comment: And to answer your last question, yes every time you need to add a dependency you need to do this. To be sure, always follow what's written in the guide (if provided) on the github page or the likes of it.

Comment: I've added an image to my answer so that maybe you may understand more quickly how and where to add you code. If you still need help with this issue, just ask and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Alright mate! It helped me a lot! Thank you so mutch